# Does anyone know what is the MAXIMUM number of versions that I can create in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Upon working on a frequently changing customer requirement I got this strange question!... I even tried to find on official help website and could NOT find an answer.

Comment: What are you changing so often. The canvas activity? The email being sent?

Comment: Hi @EazyE, I had to create only 5 to 6 versions, due to business requirement changes. But, I was just CURIOUS to know this answer! As I did not find anywhere in official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no limits to the number of versions, currently in place. However, performance could degrade if you get into high numbers of versions. It would make sense to delete old versions that are no longer relevant and if you can't - then create a new journey altogether, as a 1:1 copy.