# Number of versions in Journey Builder in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, sfmcadmin

I am trying to find number of versions that one can create in a single journey in SFMC. I found one thread [HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284026/does-anyone-know-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-versions-that-i-can-create-in-jou) which says that there is no limit on it but that is too old information. Does any one know is there any capping on the number of versions in Journey.

Thanks
R

Comment: I have made upto 90 versions of a journey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I am answering my own question here to help others as no one could provide relevant answer.

There is no hard limit on the number of versions. However, something you'll want to consider is that performance may be affected if there are many versions created. To mitigate this, you could delete older Versions that are no longer relevant or simply create a new Journey if you start to experience performance issues.

Thanks
R